Tengo problemas con laravel/sanctum unauthenticated
Estoy practicando con laravel/sanctum, estoy haciendo la peticion a localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie para obtener el token X-XSRF-TOKEN, y me sale la peticion exitosa me da la cookie, ahora estoy haciendo la peticion a localhost:8000/api/user y me sale message:unauthenticated. ¿que estoy haciendo mal?
Version de laravel 11
.env
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_ENCRYPT=false
SESSION_PATH=/
SESSION_DOMAIN=locahost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost,127.0.0.1

config/sanctum.php
 'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),

Routes/api.php
Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->all();
})->middleware('auth:sanctum');



